# Cannot download system images in Android Studio 3.0 AVD Manager or SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.0

When I try to list and download system images in AVD Manager, nothing shows up in the list. See below:
[image]
None of the three tabs show the images, even after I hit refresh. I have made sure I have a working fast Internet connection.  I have checked the SDK Manager also. Nothing related to system images is there for download. My list of SDK update sites is as follows (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml and a local repo on my system):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove Android settings directory. Make sure Android Studio is closed. On Linux you can run:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.android
```

Now, launch Android Studio and Download links should be available for system images both in AVD Manager and SDK Manager.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem just now in my Manjaro Desktop but unfortunately, the answer by @JasonStack did not work. In my case, the `/tmp` directory was full so that Android Studio could not download the repository information into the `/tmp` directory.
You can check the `/tmp` directory status using the following command.

```
df -h
```

If this is the problem, it can be fixed by removing all the files in `/tmp` directory and restarting the computer. To remove all the files in `/tmp` directory, use the following command:

```
for i in /tmp/* ; do sudo rm -rf "$i" ; done
```

Try this command without `sudo`. If there are any files left, use `sudo`.

---

If the file to download is too large, the capacity of the `/tmp` directory may not be enough. In such scenarios, follow these steps:

Create a new directory in the home directory:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
```

Append the following line to the end of `<android-studio-location>/bin/studio64.vmoptions` file and restart the Android Studio.

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/<USER>/tmp
```

Replace `<USER>` in the above line with your username.

See this question for more details: [/tmp directory in Linux Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057884/tmp-directory-in-linux-android-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

in my case,I set a not available http proxy.