# No system images could be found - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to run my app on Android Studio but when I try to create a new **virtual device**, in the system image screen, when I try to select version it is empty:

[image]

I have tried:

[Cannot download system images in Android Studio 3.0 AVD Manager or SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028876/cannot-download-system-images-in-android-studio-3-0-avd-manager-or-sdk-manager)

[No System image available when adding AVD in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999092/no-system-image-available-when-adding-avd-in-android-studio)

Comment: Well when I had that issue, after a bit of a struggle I noticed the refresh (or reload button down there) and it pretty much solved it ':D
Silly me

Comment: @ShreyanshChouhan I tried that but it still didn't work