# No System image available when adding AVD in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Just installed Android Studio and was trying to add an AVD. When I reached the "Select a system image" there were some to choose from, and I picked one and it started installing. However, the installation failed because my harddrive ran out of space. I cleaned up my harddrive and tried to add an AVD again. However, this time, when I reach the "Select a system image", there are no system images to choose from. Instead I see the message:

```
"No System image available. Are you connected to the internet?"
```

And yes, my internet is connected, and restarting Android studio did not help. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Try [ invalidates caches/restart ] option

Comment: Had similar problem and it was due to studio using up the /tmp -partition. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the SDK manager (Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager) and install some images.
Checking the "Show Package Details" checkbox allows for finer selections of what you need.

Answer (score 11):

Its to easy to do:

1. Go to SDK Manager
   [image: opening sdk manager]
2. Check the  Show Package Details Checkbox
3. Check the System Image checkboxes based on your  CPU architecture (x86 or x64) and your needs ( Google play)
   [image: checking the checkboxes]

4.Click on apply and Let it be downloaded

Done!

It worked for me hope will work for yours.

Comment: This method worked correctly for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

*Give the answer on this site for the first time, so perhaps I can`t express clearly.*

Once I happened this issue, and I run the sdkmanager application in android-sdk-path

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager;
```

and I got this output.

```
Warning: java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
```

the reason I got this is that my network can't connect the dl-google website. So I search the valid IP address, and I got this '203.208.41.36'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvqy2.png). I changed the hosts file and save it.

```
203.208.41.36 dl.google.com
```

Then I run the avd manager again, and it worked. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKmYK.png)

Comment: how is this possible like why the dns do that ? and it happened suddenly as well
i didn't believe this is the issue but actually it was and i had to add it to hosts file

Answer (score 1):

Probably your **/tmp** is full.

Close your Android Studio.

Check if exists some directory like **/tmp/PackageOperation01/** and remove it.

You should find a partition in your system with more space than your **/tmp**, let say your **/var** has more.

So create a new directory like **/var/tmp-android** and edit the file **./android-studio/bin/studio.sh** replace this line

```
VM_OPTIONS=""
```

with

```
VM_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp-android
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tools>SDK Manager>HTTP Proxy**, now select **Manual proxy configuration** then select **HTTP**, now fill as
**Host name: google.com**
**Port number: 80**

Now everything is OK

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to invalidate cache- restart after you download the system image from the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Firewall Timed Groups.

I am on my professional computer, my firewall manager (Trellix) is blocking by default when downloading libraries. In my case, Android Studio wasn't able to access to dl.google.com websites, so I had to enable the firewall timed groups.

To access it on windows, you go to notification icon at bootom right, click right on the Trellix icon, Quick settings, Enable Firewall Timed Groups.

Answer (score -2):

In my case no connection to the internet was the problem.