# no system image available are you connected to the internet

Tags: android

I can't create virtual device I see this massage
"No System image available Are you connected to the internet"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShRSW.png

and this is my Android SDK Manager

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMBun.png

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999092/no-system-image-available-when-adding-avd-in-android-studio