# No system image are available, Are you connected to the internet?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio, I tried to create a virtual device and it says to me: No system image are available, Are you connected to the internet?

What should I do ?

Comment: are you connected to the internet? Is there some kind of filter/firewall/whatever that could be blocking Internet access to Android Studio?

Comment: i am fully connected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No System image available when adding AVD in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999092/no-system-image-available-when-adding-avd-in-android-studio)

Comment: No. It did not.

Comment: which answers did you try, and what results did you get, including any error messages? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72804449/edit) your question to include that information.

Comment: did you try a VPN?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.